# Using gedit using X forwarding on remote location

Tags: 16.04, server, gedit, x11-forwarding

I have been using the following command to log in to a server :

```
 ssh user@servername -X
```

To edit I usually use the gedit on server by typing :

```
gedit filename
```

This seemed to be working fine until recently, gedit refuses to open. with no possible error displayed. I am trying to understand what might be the issue here, I cannot probe too much into the server since I do not have sudo access. If someone could help me with this it would be great :)

Comment: It is almost impossible to guess without further information. As a less than ideal work around why not use nano or vim or emacs ....

Comment: I am able to open emacs, so probably a gedit issue?

Comment: If I knew I would answer, but without some sort of error message hard to say.

Comment: Maybe it's better to ask the server administrator for help.